# How do you get clean Android OS on Galaxy S7 or LG v10?

Tags: applications

What is the path (or paths) to get a modern android phone with a clean OS?

Preferably something similar to what a Nexus provides.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

Answer (score 2):

You have to hope that the manufacturer or custom ROM creators release an "AOSP" version of the software.  For instance: Oppo has recently moved away from ColorOS towards a more stock experience, and BlackBerry's Priv has minimal changes to the Android interface.

For finding such ROMs, see [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/1465)